# What does it mean for a subspace to be stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm looking through a proof for a spectral theorem, but I can't figure out what it means for a subspace to be stable.

> $\dots \mathbb{C}v$ is $T$-stable (for some $v$ that is an
>   eigenvector of an endomorphism $T: V \to V$, where $V$ is a vector
>   space over a field $k$). Then the orthogonal complement $(\mathbb{C}v)^{\perp}$ is also $T$-stable...

Comment: (It is also common to call these spaces $T$-invariant.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set and $T$ a function on $S$. You might say that $S$ is $T$ stable or stabilized by $T$ if $T(S)\subseteq S$.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative equivalent terminology that is possibly more common in the linear algebra literature is that $S$ is $T$-invariant when $T(S) \subseteq S$.