# what do we call the range of a real function when it is a subset of the domain?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, terminology

when the image of a set under some function f is a subset of the same set, what can we say about that set? (in french it's : l'intervalle D est stable par f)

Comment: The set is *$f$-stable* or *$f$-invariant*. Look at [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312638/what-does-it-mean-for-a-subspace-to-be-stable) in linear algebra.

Comment: If you take a metric space $X$ (like an interval) and a contraction $f\colon X\rightarrow X$, it always has a fixed point according to the Banach fixed-point theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Answer (score 0):

It means that $f$ can be restricted to get a restriction function from the set to itself.